# Multiple vs Single COUNT on same col + Multiple vs Single col index

Tags: mysql, index, aggregate, alias

I have two very simple questions

#### 1. Multiple vs Single COUNT on same col

I need to perform CASE on an aggregate column like this:

```
SELECT tbl_students.school, COUNT(tbl_students.id) as students, (
  CASE
     WHEN students > 1000 THEN 'SMALL'
     WHEN students > 10000 THEN 'MEDIUM'
     WHEN students > 100000 THEN 'LARGE'
  END
) as size 
FROM tbl_students 
GROUP BY tbl_students.school
```

But MySQL does not allow using the column alias within the SELECT part. So instead of above, I'll have to write:

```
SELECT tbl_students.school, COUNT(tbl_students.id) as students, (
  CASE
     WHEN COUNT(tbl_students.id) > 1000 THEN 'SMALL'
     WHEN COUNT(tbl_students.id) > 10000 THEN 'MEDIUM'
     WHEN COUNT(tbl_students.id) > 100000 THEN 'LARGE'
  END
) as size 
FROM tbl_students
GROUP BY tbl_students.school
```

My question is "**will using COUNT multiple times on the same column actually performs COUNT multiple times? If yes, will it also result in performance issues when there are millions of records?**".

#### 2. Multiple vs Single col index

If a table has following three columns:

`tbl_students(id, username, school, firstname, lastname)`

And has composite unique key for `username` and `school`. My question is, do I need to create a separate index for `school` column if I am searching only in `school` column?

Comment: Are you missing a `GROUP BY`?

Comment: 1) No, `COUNT()` will be calculated once. If you're afraid nevertheless you may use intermediate UDV. 2) No, if the index is `(school, username)` and yes if in backward order.

Comment: @VesaKarjalainen you are right but my question was limited to `SELECT` part so it would be good to avoid any unnecessary details.


@Akina do you have any reference to what you are saying and what is intermediate UDV?

Comment: Either get rid of the `school` column or add `GROUP BY school`.  What you have does not make sense.  After that, we can look deeper into your question.

Comment: @RickJames I have added the `GROUP BY` clause as it was causing some confusion. Any feedback on second part of the question?

Comment: Renaming (`AS students`) happens after `CASE` which is why you can't use the alias in your `CASE`. It is defined that way, so it's not unique to MySQL. Typically this is solved by nesting the query as @RickJames does in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is straightforward enough and more efficient:

```
SELECT  school, 
        CASE
           WHEN students > 1000 THEN 'SMALL'
           WHEN students > 10000 THEN 'MEDIUM'
           WHEN students > 100000 THEN 'LARGE'
        END as size 
    FROM ( SELECT school,
                  COUNT(*) as students
              FROM tbl_students
              GROUP BY school
         ) AS cts
```

It would need `INDEX(school)` or any index *starting with* `school`.

Comment: I tried it but it makes the query too slow when there are millions of students.

Comment: How many schools?